# MySQL query - Get first & last rows from groups of larger query

Tags: mysql

I have a table (names) with about 10M rows (id, first, last, etc), and I need to break it down into digestible groups by last name letter (e.g. All last names ending in A in groups of 100), and grabbing the first and last record of each group.

I'm not sure what the most efficient way is, and not familiar with sub-querys. I think I should count the rows by last name letter (all the A's), divide it by 100, and select the first and last row?  Struggling here to get an efficient query to work.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM names 
WHERE last REGEXP '^[A].*$' / 100
```

gives me count of groups

```
SELECT COUNT (id), min(first), max(last), 
       (SELECT COUNT(id) 
        FROM names 
        WHERE last REGEXP '^[A].*$' / 100) 
FROM names
```

can't get right syntax

Comment: Why are you dividing a string containing a regular expression by 100?

Comment: If you want to divide the count by 100, it should be `COUNT(id)/100`.

Comment: It is not clear what the signficance of "100" is here.  Are you talking about wanting to get paginated results? In other words, why split the result set by letter first if you only want 100 rows. I assuming that with 10M records you will have >> than 100 rows per letter. Also, no need to for overhead of `REGEXP` here.  Just use `LIKE` for this use case.

Comment: You also are not specifying any sort of ordering at all currently, so it is unclear what first and last actually mean.  If you have not specified an order, first and last may vary from one query to the next as no order is guaranteed.  This also means what is in one set of 100 from one query to the next will change. You may want to take a step back in your question and actually describe the problem you are trying to solve, as I don't how grabbing records 1,100,101,200,201,300,301,400, etc. from all records starting with A is a meaningful pursuit.

Comment: What's your Primary Key? I have a table with names (and other info about the person) but also have a primary key that auto increments - if I wanted to do what you do, that's what I'd use.

Comment: @MikeBrant I think `first` and `last` are first name and last name. This sounds like a phone book, and he wants to divide it first into sections by the initial, then divide that into pages of 100 names. And like in a printed phone book or dictionary, he wants to show the range of names on the page, e.g. `Jackson-Jones`.

Comment: the idea is to have each last name letter () broken down into groups, then paginated from there - that way there isn't 5000 pages of 100 names, and rather 100 pages, with each having 50 paginated pages.  So for the letter A, all last names are first grouped into a list from Aaaron to Adelson, Adelsr-Afallo, etc..., then each of those paginated to maybe 20-30 pages.  it's an seo thing to create reasonable chunks for google to crawl...

Comment: @MikeBrant - exactly

Comment: @devellis OK That is better explanation and should be in the question.  You just want to figure out how to both paginate the list as well as to determine what labels should be shown in the application for pagination.

Comment: @MikeBrant - I have the pagination down once I get the list. in fact I already having it return all last names by letter, then paginated.  I just can't figure out the mysql query prior to that to get the range of names.  as the database grows, those last names will change with every query and will need to adjust the group sizes to keep pagination to 30ish pages per grouping.

Answer (score 0):

OK let's start with the basics.  First of all, to do the pagination, you would need a query like:

```
SELECT last, first
FROM names
WHERE last LIKE '%a'
ORDER BY last ASC
LIMIT 0,100 /* query for first page */
```

The challenge you than have is how to get the very first and last name from each of these groups. Unfortunately, there is no really straightforward way to do this other than either manually inspecting the first and last record of the result set above and then repeating the same thing over and over for each increment of 100.  You would be best served to use a application-side DB library that allows you to easily skip your pointer within the result set.  Assuming you have ability to easily move the pointer, you could also do this with a single non-paginated query and just move your point to the 1st, 100th, 101st, 200th, etc. record to extract the value.

This is probably a pretty unreasonable action for your application to take everytime you are wanting to render your navigation elements, as you would need to do this 26 times.  This might cause you to rethink you navigation experience altogether, or come up with a solution to reasonably cache the results for use in navigational display.

Alternatives could include using a surrogate counter field to number all rows from 1 to x for each first letter grouping and using mathematical mean to get the rows (i.e. modulus):

```
SET @x=0;
SELECT `last`, `first`
FROM (
    SELECT @x:=@x+1 AS `counter`, `last`, `first`
    FROM names
    WHERE last LIKE '%a'
    ORDER BY `last` ASC
) AS all_rows
WHERE `counter` MOD 100 = 0
OR `counter` MOD 100 = 1
```

Though again you would need to do this 26 times if you wanted to generate all of your second level navigation options.